# How to echo integer value(id) to name from db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently started coding and fairly new top php and codeigniter.

I am wondering how to echo values from db to view file if all the values are integer in db. I may be wrong in explaining, what I am trying to do is lets say I have countries in db but they are in the form of integer(id). I can echo the integer fine but how to convert it to country name?

Conteroller:

```
public function index() {
    $data['title'] = "Dynamic Title";
    $data['details'] = $this->model_users->property_details();
    $this->load->view('headfoot/header-item', $data);
    $this->load->view('item', $data);
    $this->load->view('headfoot/footer-item');
}
```

Model:

```
function property_details(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('all_properties');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query; 
}
```

View:

```
<?php foreach($details as $details): ?>
<?= $details->property_country; ?>
<?= $details->property_state; ?>
<?= $details->property_city; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

It only echo integers as they are saved as (id)integers in 'all_properties'.

Just to show tables that were used to insert attributes in db

```
function getCountry(){
    $this->db->select('v_country_id,v_country_name');
    $this->db->from('vbc_country');
    $this->db->order_by('v_country_name', 'asc'); 
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query; 
}
function getData($loadType,$loadId){
    if($loadType=="state"){
        $fieldList='id,v_state_name as name';
        $table='vbc_state';
        $fieldName='country_id';
        $orderByField='v_state_name';                       
    }elseif($loadType == "region"){
        $fieldList='id,v_state_region_name as name';
        $table='vbc_state_region';
        $fieldName='state_id';
        $orderByField='v_state_region_name';
    }else{
        $fieldList='id,v_city_name as name';
        $table='vbc_city';
        $fieldName='state_region_id';
        $orderByField='v_city_name';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your Question, at general in data bases if there is a Country class you would find parameter in it with [ code_country = (id) ] and the [ name ]

and you would use the query as something like this

```
"select name from country where id=code_contry"
```

and the output should be your country as a string.

Comment: Thanks. I have details for country, city, state in 3 different tables and for a particular post I have their ids in db.

Comment: did I help? cause if I didn't try to explain more so I can Help :D

Comment: do you have access to the database? cause what you just added didn't help either.

Comment: I appreciate you are helping.. I know what the problem is but dont know how to fix.. I have names & id for country, city & states in 3 separate tables other then 'all_properties'. but integers values are inserted in 'all_properties' and thats where I am trying to echo it from. Hence it only echo integer values not name

Comment: well can you List the columns and attributes for every table in the database? I know I'm asking too much, but this is the only way I can understand

Comment: I have just added that but those were only used to insert... data is inserted in 'all_properties'.

Comment: don't you have any idea on how the data are stored? cause it's pretty much not helping either.  can you **print_r($query)** and let me see how the data is stored?